# PhotoScroller Zooming/Appearance

Tags: iphone, ios

I have been looking through the code and .xib files which are included in the Photoscroller app provided by Apple. Through all of this and a few internet searches I have not been able to locate where the button which controls whether the image is 1x or 2x zoom is located in the code or any events which are fired as a result of clicking it.

If someone cant point me to where this button is held that would be very helpful. My end goal is to implement the tiling in full screen so any advice on this would also be appreciated.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1x/2x button is not in the application at all. The app is set to iPhone only so when you run it on the iPad it still runs at iPhone size. Any time you run an iPhone only app on an iPad it will display the 1x/2x button allowing you to zoom the app to a bigger size. You can see the difference by going to the Project Build Settings and changing Targeted Device Family to iPhone/iPad and running it again.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out it felt like I was on a wild goose chase because I was